Angular 18 - Browser tab memory usage
I'm currently working on a big Angular application and as the title says I've got problems with my browser tab memory usage.
At the first opening of my app in a new tab, the memory usage is quite ok (≈ 300Mo) but at each live relaod the memory usage double up and finally "stabilizes" at 1.2Go which make the app unusable (the only solution is to open the app in a new app).

I want to specify that pretty much each of my observable are handled onDestroy and that i'm using lazy loading routing.
And it only happen in dev configuration.
Did you ever add this problem and/or solved it.
Regards.

is live reload a standard dev server live reload which is doing just a page refresh?

Yeah when the app is rebuilding after saved changes

I mean the app is resetted, the js engine is restarted and everything you had in memory just dies and starts again during page refresh. are you using some persistency? for example sessionStorage in your app?

I'm using sessionStorage and localStorage. When I check in browser console (i'm using Brave but it's the same with every browser I've test) Application > Storage it show a stable 12.1Mo of cache storage.
